# Highest and lowest number

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Am trying to write a function that takes an array as a parameter, and then returns the highest and lowest number from the array without sorting the array.  Below is my code, How can I make it better.

```
function lowestAndHighest(arr) {
    this.lowest = 0;
    this.highest = 1;

    //This function returns the lowest number
    this.lowestNum = () => {
        arr.forEach(elem => {
            if(this.lowest > elem) {
                return this.lowest =  elem;    
            } 
        });
        return this.lowest;
    }

    //This function returns the higest number
    this.highestNum = () => {
        arr.forEach(elem => {
            if(this.highest < elem) {
                this.highest = elem;
            }
        });
        return this.highest;
    }
}

let num = new lowestAndHighest([30,3,6,8,1,0,-10, -60]);
console.log(num.lowestNum());
console.log(num.highestNum());
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your code would compute the lowest number in [3, 4, 5] as 0, and the highest number in [-3, -4, -5] as 1.

Comment: Yes exactly the problem

Comment: Welcome to CR! I'm voting to close this as [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because the code is not working as intended. Having said that, why not simply use builtins: `Math.max(...[1,4,5,6,7])`?

Answer (score 1):

`How can I make [the code presented] better`

Give [Test First](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) a try.

Document your source code, *in the source code*: what is the goal of "any" given piece? ("The `This function returns the higest number` comments" *are* a step in the right direction. (Your IDE doesn't check spelling?))

Be consistent. (In addition to a double blank,) There is an irritating difference between

```
if(this.lowest > elem) {
    return this.lowest =  elem;
}
```

and

```
if(this.highest < elem) {
    this.highest = elem;
}
```

If your goal was to keep the number of comparisons low, there is a simple technique taking you half way to optimal.

(For all I don't know about ECMAScript & JSDoc, The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work might be

```
/* Returns minimum and maximum value in values
 * @param {Array<number>} values */
function lowestAndHighest(values) {
    return [ Math.min.apply(Math, values),
             Math.max.apply(Math, values) ];
}
```

)

Answer (score -1):

I just saw my error now

```
function lowestAndHighest(arr) {

    this.lowest = arr[0];//corrected
    this.highest = arr[0];//corrected

    //This function returns the lowest number
    this.lowestNum = () => {
        arr.forEach(elem => {
            if(this.lowest > elem) {
                return this.lowest =  elem;    
            } 
        });
        return this.lowest;
    }

    //This function returns the higest number
    this.highestNum = () => {
        arr.forEach(elem => {
            if(this.highest < elem) {
                this.highest = elem;
            }
        });
        return this.highest;
    }
}

let num = new lowestAndHighest([30,3,6,8,1,0,-10, -60]);
console.log(num.lowestNum());
console.log(num.highestNum());
```

Comment: Now, what is the result for [Martin R's arrays](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220096/highest-and-lowest-number/220097#comment425285_220096)?

Comment: It is working as intended

Comment: I misread the lambda assigned to this.lowestNum - irritating for the extraneous `return` the lambda assigned to this.highestNum doesn't show.